# This should be simple. Can I adjust the margin-bottom of an individual list item?

Tags: html, css

I created an HTML form that incorporates a CSS list.  However, I would like to add 10 pixels or so after the "Last Name" field and after the "Confirmation" field of the below HTML form.  Is this possible?

```
<form>
<ul>
<li><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="firstName" size="35" id="firstName"/></li>
<li><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="lastName" size="35" id="lastName"/></li>

<li><label for="passid">Password:</label></li>
<li><input type="password" name="password" size="35" id="password"/></li>
<li><label for="confirmation">Confirmation:</label></li>
<li><input type="password" name="confirmation" size="35"id="confirmation"/></li>

<li><label for="email">Email:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="email" size="35" id="email"/></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

I made several CSS and HTML modifications, like the following, which had no effect:

```
form ul li.extra
{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

<li class="extra"><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></li>
<li class="extra"><input type="text" name="lastName" size="35" id="lastName"/></li>
```

I've also tried simpler things, like HTML line breaks, but none had any effect on the layout of my page.

Is is possible to adjust the margin-bottom property of an individual list item?

Thank you!

Comment: What you show should work. Can you build a JSfiddle with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but a quick way is to set the inline style of the LI you're interested in:

```
<li style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Whatever</li>
```

But a better way would be to add the class, which is obviously easier to apply to other individual LI tags:

```
li.single_li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

<li class="single_li">Whatever</li>
```

If it's not working, it could be being overridden by a parent class / style, try the following in your css / style:

**CSS**

```
li.single_li {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

**Inline**

```
<li style="margin-bottom: 15px !important;">Whatever</li>
```

The addition of **!important** makes sure it gets applied and not overwritten by a parent class.

Added [jsFiddle example of inline style](http://jsfiddle.net/zvBgS/)

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working either.  Could it be conflicting with other CSS entries?

Comment: @TimeBomb006 updated answer, it may be being overwritten - but this should definitely work.

Comment: Yeah this should definitely be working like it is in JSFiddle, but it's still not.  I'm on Chrome, and this has me dumbfounded.  I just realized that it's actually not updating ANY CSS changes.  I removed whole chunks of CSS, saved, cleared cache, and restarted the browser, and it still appeared identical.  It's the same with Firefox.  Strange!

Comment: @TimeBomb006 yeah that is strange - are you editing straight off an FTP server or locally?  Try using debug mode in Chrome (CTRL+SHIFT+J) and clearing the cache that way once you've updated your markup.

Comment: I'm doing it on a VMWare image and editing it locally, but I've never had an issue like this before.  I've had issues with Java caching on some classes, but I resolved them by clearing the Java cache.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

Set a class on the li:

```
HTML:

<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="extra">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li.extra{
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: actually, I didn't. I added my inline method first as a quick way to get my answer on here - I was likely in the middle of editing (adding the extra info) when you posted.